# Forcing a ng-src reload

Tags: angularjs

How can I force angularjs to reload an image with an ng-src attribute, when the url of the image has not changed, but its contents has?

```
<div ng-controller='ctrl'>
    <img ng-src="{{urlprofilephoto}}">
</div>
```

An uploadReplace service that performs a file upload, is replacing the content  of the image, but not the url.

```
app.factory('R4aFact', ['$http', '$q', '$route', '$window', '$rootScope',
function($http, $q, $route, $window, $rootScope) {
    return {
        uploadReplace: function(imgfile, profileid) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                fd = new FormData(),
                d = $q.defer();
            fd.append('profileid', profileid);
            fd.append('filedata', imgfile);
            xhr.onload = function(ev) {
                var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                    if (data.status == 'OK') {
                        d.resolve(data);
                    } else {
                        d.reject(data);
                    }
                });
            }
            xhr.open('post', '/profile/replacePhoto', true)
            xhr.send(fd)
            return d.promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

When the uploadReplace returns, I don't know how I can force the image to reload

```
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'R4aFact', function($scope, R4aFact){
    $scope.clickReplace = function() {
        R4aFact.uploadReplace($scope.imgfile, $scope.pid).then(function(){
            // ??  here I need to force to reload the imgsrc 
        })
    }
}])
```

Comment: Set `urlprofilephoto` empty and then set it to the url again.

Comment: May be with `$scope.$apply` ?

Comment: Making the url empty and then setting it again, sends a bogus request to the server, which should be avoided.  
The $scope.$apply is not the issue.  The anser of the factory function is already in $rootScope.$apply

Answer (score 78):

An easy workaround is to append a unique timestamp to ng-src to force image reload as follows:

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.imageUrl = $scope.imageUrl + '?' + new Date().getTime();
});
```

or

```
angular.module('ngSrcDemo', [])
    .controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.app = {
        imageUrl: "http://example.com/img.png"
    };
    var random = (new Date()).toString();
    $scope.imageSource = $scope.app.imageUrl + "?cb=" + random;
}]);
```

Comment: $scope.imageUrl += '?' + Date.now();

Comment: Had to place code in a $timeout(function() {  (code here)  });  So it wouldn't break $digest.

Answer (score 28):

Perhaps it could be as simple as adding a decache query string to the image URL? ie.

```
var imageUrl = 'http://i.imgur.com/SVFyXFX.jpg';
$scope.decachedImageUrl = imageUrl + '?decache=' + Math.random();
```

This should force it to reload.

Answer (score 16):

An "angular approach" could be creating your own filter to add a random querystring parameter to the image URL.

Something like this:

```js
.filter("randomSrc", function () {
    return function (input) {
        if (input) {
            var sep = input.indexOf("?") != -1 ? "&" : "?";
            return input + sep + "r=" + Math.round(Math.random() * 999999);
        }
    }
})
```

Then you can use it like this:

```html
<img ng-src="{{yourImageUrl | randomSrc}}" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Try This

```
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'R4aFact', function($scope, R4aFact){
$scope.clickReplace = function() {
    R4aFact.uploadReplace($scope.imgfile, $scope.pid).then(function(response){
        $scope.urlprofilephoto  = response + "?" + new Date().getTime(); //here response is ur image name with path.
    });
}
 }])
```

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to make a directive to put random param in the src, but only if the image changes, so I don't mess that much with the caching.

I use it to update the user's profile pic in the navbar when they update it via AJAX, which doesn't happen that often.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular
    .module("exampleApp", [])
    .directive("eaImgSrc", directiveConstructor);

  function directiveConstructor() {
    return { link: link };

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.eaImgSrc, function(currentSrc, oldSrc) {
        if (currentSrc) {
          // check currentSrc is not a data url,
          // since you can't append a param to that
          if (oldSrc && !currentSrc.match(/^data/)) {
            setSrc(currentSrc + "?=" + new Date().getTime());
          } else {
            setSrc(currentSrc);
          }
        } else {
          setSrc(null);
        }
      })

      function setSrc(src) { element[0].src = src; }
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="exampleApp">
  <div>
    <img ea-img-src="src"></img>
  </div>

  <button ng-click="src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100/FF0000'">IMG 1</button>
  <button ng-click="src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100/0000FF'">IMG 2</button>
  <button ng-click="src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100/00FF00'">IMG 3</button>
</div>
```