# How to display dynamically loaded images with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to display an avatar of an user once the user logs in:

```
<img src="{{(API_PROVIDER.domain + user.avatar.small_thumb.url)}}" alt="" class="img-circle size-30x30">
```

But the above code only works if I reload the page after login. How can I get it to work without having to programmatically reload the page?

PS: The above resolves to something like this: www.example.com/api/something.jpg

**EDIT:**

I have tried using `ng-src` instead of `src` and it didn't work. As to the other comment whether my variables were in scope, yes, the avatar link is only defined when the user signs in. Then I use `$state.go('somewhere')` to change the template, in which case I'd image the variable should be updated.

Here's my main controller:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('admin')
    .controller('MainController', MainController);

  /** @ngInject */
  function MainController($timeout, webDevTec, toastr, $scope, $http, authenticatedUser, Session, $anchorScroll, API_PROVIDER) {

    ...

    $scope.session = Session;
    $scope.user = Session.user;
    $scope.API_PROVIDER = API_PROVIDER;

    ...

  }
})();
```

Here ar the components of my Session (reduced for brevity):

```
...
this.create = function(user) {
    this.user = user;
    this.role = user._role;
    this.token = user.auth_token;
    this.userRole = user._role;
};
return this;
...
```

And how the session is saved for later retrieval:

```
...
$window.sessionStorage["userInfo"] = JSON.stringify(loginData);
...
```

Do I need to use `$apply()` in this case? If yes, how so?

**EDIT 3: Here's how I'm setting my `Session` object**

```
authService.login = function(user, success, error, $state) {
  $http.post(API_PROVIDER.full_path + 'signin', user).success(function(data) {

  if(data.success){
    var user = data.user;
    var loginData = user;
    $window.sessionStorage["userInfo"] = JSON.stringify(loginData);
    delete loginData.password;
    Session.create(loginData);
    $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);
    success(loginData);
  } else {
    $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed);
    error();
  } 
  });
};
```

Comment: try `ng-src` instead of `src`

Comment: aside from the comment above, your data doesn't look like it's in scope. If it's not, then you will have to run the `$apply()` function after your data is updated so the template knows your data has changed.

Comment: You show how you set the session storage - can you also show how you restore this info? It might be that you need to `$apply` there.

Comment: Also, is your `<img> tag in a ng-repeater or something similar? Maybe _that_ part cannot resolve the scope change.
As an aside, you should always use ng-src instead of src.

Comment: Oh, try to leave out the `()` from the image url! Doing `(a + b)` in javascript evaluates to a constant string, so angular has, initially before login, an constant there inside the {{}}. So even if you change the variables, the initial constant was already resolved and would not be recalculated.
So maybe calculate that url somewhere else (on the Session directly?) or leave out the round braces in the angular expression in the <img> tag.
Can't tell for sure, but that seems the case.

Answer (score 0):

Force reload images

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21731946/2906183

Apply time stamp and call `$scope.$appy()`

Answer (score 0):

Use fall back

HTML:

```
<img fallback-src="http://google.com/favicon.ico" ng-src="{{image}}"/>

JS:

myApp.directive('fallbackSrc', function () {
  var fallbackSrc = {
    link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      iElement.bind('error', function() {
        angular.element(this).attr("src", iAttrs.fallbackSrc);
      });
    }
   }
   return fallbackSrc;
});
```