# $cordovaFile not going well with cache of Ionic resulting in showing wrong picture

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-file

Following scenario

1. going to `main.admin.emergencyDetail.photos`
2. loading every image and showing as list view
3. clicking one image in the list opens a modal which enables with ionic slider to slide through the image list
4. going back to `main.admin.emergencyDetail`
5. going back to `main.admin` and choosing a new emergency from a list (going to another `main.admin.emergencyDetail.photos`
6. opening a photo from the list to show in modal: Now the old pictures from last time being on this view showing and from now on only those loaded from point 3. are showing in every `main.admin.emergencyDetail.photos` state
7. closing app and reopening enables me to reset this bug. as soon i am on point 3. it takes again this image i opened now in every `main.admin.emergencyDetail.photos` state

The funny thing is: when I inspected the filesystem `file:///data/data/<appname>/cache` then the photoCache folder got deleted successfully by going back one state (as I do in 4.) which means the old picture is cached somehow by ionic. I think I can put somewhere `window.cache.clear()` but am not quite sure where to....

```
'use strict';
angular.module('main')
.controller('AdminEmergencyCtrl', function (Action, $window, $state, $ionicSideMenuDelegate,
                                          $location, $rootScope, $ionicHistory, $timeout,
                                          Rest, $stateParams, $log, uiGmapGoogleMapApi,
                                          $mdToast, $ionicPopup, $ionicModal, $scope,
                                          $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $cordovaFile, $q) {
// Authenticate
($rootScope.authenticated.state &&
$rootScope.authenticated.type === 'Admin') ? '' : $location.url('main/inactive');

$log.log('Hello from your Controller: AdminEmergencyCtrl in module main:. This is your controller:', this);

// Settings
$rootScope.$broadcast('checkMenuButton', {});
$ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true);
$scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function (scopes, states) {
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    $cordovaFile.removeRecursively(cordova.file.cacheDirectory, 'photoCache')
      .then(function (success) {
        $log.log('($ionicView.leave) cacheDirectory/photoCache cleared');
      }, function (error) {
        $log.log('($ionicView.leave) cacheDirectory/photoCache clearing error:');
        $log.log(error);
      });
  }, false);
});

// Initialize values
var ctrl = this;
ctrl.emergency = {};

ctrl.currentUser = Action.getDeviceID();
ctrl.map = {};
ctrl.showMap = ($ionicHistory.currentStateName() === 'main.admin.emergencyDetail');
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function (scopes, sates) {
  // reassign boolean to prevent strange loading behaviour of google maps
  ctrl.showMap = ($ionicHistory.currentStateName() === 'main.admin.emergencyDetail');
});
ctrl.assigned = null;

ctrl.hasImages = false;
ctrl.isLoading = true;
$scope.images = [];
ctrl.marker = {};

// Functions declarations
ctrl.getEmergency = function () {
  Rest.getEmergency($stateParams.id,
    function (success) {
      var data = angular.fromJson(success);
      var lat = data.Lat;
      var long = data.Long;
      ctrl.emergency = data;
      ctrl.assigned = data.HandledByID;
      ctrl.map = {center: {latitude: lat, longitude: long}, zoom: 15};
      ctrl.marker = {
        id: 0,
        coords: {latitude: lat, longitude: long}
      };
      ctrl.showMap = true;
    },
    function (error) {
      $log.log(error);
    });
};

/**
 * Folder creating -> Files creating -> writing in files -> returning promise for further handling
 *
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
ctrl.fillTempFolder = function () {
  return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve(fillTempFolderSuccess());
  });
};

function fillTempFolderSuccess () {
  $log.log('AM IN ctrl.fillTempFolder');
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    $cordovaFile.createDir(cordova.file.cacheDirectory, 'photoCache', true)
      .then(function (success) {
        $log.log('AM IN $cordovaFile.createDir');
        $scope.images.forEach(function (item) {
          var blob = new Blob([Action.convertDataURIToBinary(item.src)], {type: 'image/jpg'});
          $cordovaFile.createFile(cordova.file.cacheDirectory + 'photoCache/', item.name, true).then(
            function (success) {
              $log.log('(CREATE FILE) Success');
              $cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.cacheDirectory + 'photoCache/', item.name, blob, true)
                .then(function (success) {
                  $log.log('(WRITE FILE) Success');
                }, function (error) {
                  $log.log('(WRITE FILE) Error');
                  $log.log(error);
                });
            },
            function (error) {
              $log.log('(CREATE FILE) Error');
              $log.log(error);
            }
          );
        });
      }, function (error) {
        $log.log('(CREATE DIR) Could not write to FileSystem');
      });
  }, false);
}

ctrl.loadPictures = function (lastPic) {
  Rest.getNextPicture($stateParams.id, lastPic,
    function (success) {
      var data = angular.fromJson(success);
      var item = {src: 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + data.Data, name: data.Pic};
      $scope.images.push(item);
      $log.log('pic loaded: ' + data.Pic);
      ctrl.hasImages = true;
      ctrl.loadPictures(data.Pic);
    },
    function (error) {
      ctrl.isLoading = false;
      $log.log(cordova.file.cacheDirectory + 'photoCache/');
      ctrl.fillTempFolder().then(function (success) {
        $timeout(function () {
          $log.log('CREATING MODAL');
          $scope.modal = $ionicModal.fromTemplate(
            '<div class="modal image-modal transparent" ng-click="closeModal()">' +
            '<ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideChanged(index)" show-pager="false">' +
            '<ion-slide ng-repeat="oImage in images">' +
            '<img ng-src="' + cordova.file.cacheDirectory + 'photoCache/{{oImage.name}}" class="fullscreen-image" />' +
            '</ion-slide>' +
            '</ion-slide-box>' +
            '</div>', {
              scope: $scope,
              animation: 'slide-in-up'
            });
        }, 3000);
      });
    }
  );
};

ctrl.showPicturesPage = function () {
  $state.go('main.admin.emergencyDetail.photos', {'id': $stateParams.id});
};

$scope.openModal = function () {
  $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(0);
  $scope.modal.show();
};

$scope.closeModal = function () {
  $scope.modal.hide();
};

// Called each time the slide changes
$scope.slideChanged = function (index) {
  $scope.slideIndex = index;
};

// Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
  $scope.modal.remove();
});

// Call this functions if you need to manually control the slides
$scope.next = function () {
  $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next();
};

$scope.previous = function () {
  $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.previous();
};

$scope.goToSlide = function (index) {
  $scope.modal.show();
  $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(index);
};

// Called each time the slide changes
$scope.slideChanged = function (index) {
  $scope.slideIndex = index;
};

// Functions run
if ($ionicHistory.currentStateName() === 'main.admin.emergencyDetail') {
  ctrl.getEmergency();
} else {
  ctrl.loadPictures('');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by adding a timestamp to the ng-src path.

Source: [Stackoverflow - forcing a ng-src reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845298/forcing-a-ng-src-reload)