# Function wont stop running angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im having a bit of trouble I cant figure out where Im going wrong...

I have a function that gets a user profile picture from the database like so..

```
userPic(userId) {
    this._profileService.getProfilePictureByUserId(userId).subscribe(result => {
    return 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + result.profilePicture;
  });
}
```

then in my html

```
<div *ngFor="let data of returnedData">
<img [src]="userPic(data.lastModifiedUser.id)" alt="User Profile Picture">
</div>
```

So Im getting back 99 objects in the data array so this loops 99 times

but everytime I run my application this happens 
and my application crashes... Im not sure what Im doing wrong??

[image]

**EDIT**

I have tried to do this...

```
<div *ngFor="let data of data; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
    <img [src]="userPic(angel.lastModifiedUser.id)" alt="User Profile Picture">
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
userPic(userId) {
  this._profileService.getProfilePictureByUserId(userId).subscribe(result => 
{
    return 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + result.profilePicture;
  });
}

trackByFn(index: any , item: any) {
    return index;
}
```

but the application is still crashing

Comment: Is something toggling the return value between the three cases? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845298/forcing-a-ng-src-reload seems to indicate changing this will cause a reload of the source. Not really familiar with Angular so I hope this helps.

Comment: `getFriendProfilePictureById.subscribe()` is an **async** operation that executes when `userPic()` is called. However, `userPic()` will return never return the subscribed value unless it went to the `console.log('didnt run')` block. You should understand how (subscribing to) Observables work before fixing the code.

Answer (score 1):

Return `Observable<string>` and use `async` pipe in `[src]` attribute and use `trackby` in `*ngFor` directive

```
userPic(profilePictureId, userId): Observable<string> {
    if (profilePictureId && userId && this.tenantId) {
      console.log('getprofilepicture');
      return this._profileService.getFriendProfilePictureById(profilePictureId, userId, this.tenantId).pipe(map(result => {
        if (result && result.profilePicture) {
            return '../../../assets/img/default-profile-picture.png';
            // return 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + result.profilePicture;
        } else {
          return '../../../assets/img/default-profile-picture.png';
        }
    }));
    } else {
      console.log('didnt run');
      return Observable.of('../../../assets/img/default-profile-picture.png');
    }
  }

trackByFnById(index, item) {
    return item.lastModifiedUser.id;
}
```

template

```
<div *ngFor="let data of returnedData; trackBy: trackByFnById">
    <img [src]="userPic(data.lastModifiedUser.profilePictureGuid, data.lastModifiedUser.id) | async" alt="User Profile Picture">
</div>
```

Remember to import the necessary modules and libraries.

Comment: Hey Ive done what you said but im geting these errors.. `cannot read property 'id' of undefined at DefaultIterableDiffer.DashboardInnerComponent.trackByFnById`

Comment: What type is the array? is it homogeneous? Check that the sea array of the type you mark in the question. https://angular.io/api/core/TrackByFunction#call

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest moving you async method to you component and saving your called pictures into a new array, then loop through that in your html like so:

```
private dataset = []; // guessing this is already populated with user information
public userPics = []; // use this to store your user pictures

private getUserPics(): void { // call this after you have filled you dataset with user information if that would be in your ngOnInit() or some other method
  for (const id of this.dataset) {
    this._profileService.getProfilePictureByUserId(id)
      .subscribe(
        res => { this.userPics.push('data:image/jpeg;base64,' + res.profilePicture); },
        err => { console.log(err); }
      );
  }
}

<div *ngFor="let pic of userPics">
  <img [src]="pic" alt="User Profile Picture">
</div>
```

You might also want to post your _profileService.getProfilePictureByUserId() function code, it could potentially be causing you issues as well.